# Is it possible to have rails log errors when seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, random-seed

I have a rails app with a lot of information in the seed process. Is there a way to set it so that it logs to one of the log files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your just running your seeds with the `rake db:seed` task you could do:

```
$ rake db:seed --trace
```

Comment: I trace right now  - i guess the most logical thing is just to catpture the standard output into a file. Are --trace pieces just stderror. Is there an environment for seeding specifically?

Comment: Well by default it seeds to development, but you can specify with the RAILS_ENV argument.  You should be able to use Rails.logger if there is something specific you want to log, but if your just trying to capture an error into the log file then you'll need to pipe the trace output into a specified file.  I guess I'm not sure exactly what it is your trying to log.

Answer (score 5):

Rails.logger.debug("Message") will go to the log/development.log file.

You can do this in console `tail -f log/development.log` to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
say_with_time("Doing this and that") do
  # seed stuff
end
```

to make your seeds more verbose, and redirect to a file via '> log'.
I suppose you could hijack the logger at init time and use a file-logger instead, if you don't like the '> log' solution.

Comment: that's kinda what I was thinking. It seems like I almost would like to create a different environment that is seed-specific. And perhaps creates a timestamped-file for each run.